# A thousand nested if/and/or

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a huge "sheet application", in one row, and one of the fields, called "price" literally has 433 "IF" statements in the formula bar. Basically, there's a lot of options, and based on them, I have to change the price in the field (if user picks option 1, set price 1, and so on). I was just wondering if there was a more sane way of writing that, because

1. it's seriously tiring and incomprehensible
2. it usually doesn't even work because I have to throw a IF(AND()) and IF(OR()) from time to time which breaks my workflow, and makes debugging impossible.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example

Comment: @player0 the sheet is a mess and written in a different language, just making a reprex would take a ton of time. It's really nothing special, it has 2 dynamic drop downs. Picking an option from dropdown A changes dropdown B, and based on the selected option from the dropdown B, the price is set. The problem is I have to write if/and statements for every single option in the dropdown, which is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `AND` you can use multiplication `*` and instead of `OR` use sum `+` - that way you can easily use `ARRAYFORMULA` if needed. also have a look here: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471** for alternatives

---

### update

try this instead of your pstebin formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF((D24<>"")*(E24=""), 
 VLOOKUP(D24, {data!A:B; data!F1:G23}, 2, 0), 
 VLOOKUP(D24&E24, {{data!F24:F37&data!F50; data!F28&data!F49}, 
 {data!I23; data!I23; data!I23; data!I23:I29; 
  data!I29; data!I29; data!I29; data!I30; data!G28}}, 2, 0))))
```

[image]

and data sheet:

[image: 0]

Comment: I don't see how I can apply that to my specific case tho

Comment: depends on your sheet which is unknown... can you at least share your long IF formula?

Comment: Yup, this is a part of the formula

https://pastebin.com/1TEu2wvN

Comment: Wow, looks like you could have a push in the direction of `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` & `MATCH` or even `QUERY` for example. Even more options, but never seen anyone write out all these options before.

Comment: @dantevn5 can you share a screenshot of your **data** sheet?

Comment: @player0 Yeah, it's a real mess tho that doesn't bother me cuz I just use it as a reference. I could also use some help with those functions, I don't think I get them. https://imgur.com/czcyChG

Comment: @JvdV they threw this dumb af problem on me, and I'm not an excel expert, that's why I'm struggling. I honestly don't understand any of those, I just stick with if,then,else,and,or, I'm used to that because of programming.

Comment: Ok I just figured I can use arrayformula to make this process a lot easier, however, the result doesn't stay in one cell, it spreads throughout the column, and has like 100 "false" and just one true, based on position. Any way I can only keep the result inside the price cell, and just ignore/delete all the false ones?

Comment: @player0 Interesting, do you mind explaining the formula to me? The result is #NA, says it couldn't find a value where it joined my D24 and E24. Still, thanks a lot, I know it is very annoying.

Comment: @player0 sorry for being an ass, here's the doc https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Mcl29qmhsqsLssTWrvdLacvTUTkwiyE/edit#gid=1706153928

You probably won't understand a thing, but the only sheets that matter are TV and data. You can see under the "Cijena" field is where I put your formula.

Comment: sheet is private. you need to share it

Comment: @player0 Sorry, can't share it, I don't know if my coworkers will know if its shared and this is kind of sensitive information, the xlsx file is uploaded there
https://easyupload.io/ijzc3x

Comment: see how it works here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Fio7HHHD0GuCrhfBikEUQ4EnyFOcX5ub8NISy4FinE/edit#gid=638492507

Comment: Yeah, that looks useful, I'll see what I can do with that. I'll accept your answer, thanks man.